# How can I trace a program by step in?

Tags: c++, exception, debugging, winapi, reverse-engineering

### Main problem:

I'm trying to write my own tracer, but I can't find any material on how I can trace the program itself,
there is no information in msdn about EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP and how it can be called. Again, as far as I understand, I
need to somehow call EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP, but how? After the first EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT exception, my application
just starts and continues until any of its actions are performed. If I just put a breakpoint before each instruction, and then remove it,
then I will constantly generate EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT, and not EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP,

1)[Debug loop link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/writing-the-debugger-s-main-loop)

### MY CODE:

```
BOOL TraceProcess(PEInformation& PEInformation)
{
    DEBUG_EVENT debugEvent; Regs Regs;

    bool IsRunning = true;     
    CONTEXT Context{}; Context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    HANDLE hThread;
    while (IsRunning)
    {
        if (!WaitForDebugEvent(&debugEvent, INFINITE))
        {
            // Error handling
            DebugActiveProcessStop(PEInformation.processInfo.dwProcessId);
            return FALSE;
        } 

        // Process the debug event based on its type
        switch (debugEvent.dwDebugEventCode)
        {
        case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
            switch (debugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
            {
            case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
                hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, debugEvent.dwThreadId);
                if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, &Context))
                {
                    std::cerr << "GetThreadContext failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                    break;
                }

                std::cout << "rip: " << std::hex << Context.Rip << std::endl;
                break;
            case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP:
                hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, debugEvent.dwThreadId);
                if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, &Context))
                {
                    std::cerr << "GetThreadContext failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                    break;
                }

                std::cout << "rip: " << std::hex << Context.Rip << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            break;

        case CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle newly created threads
            // Process debugEvent.u.CreateThread for detailed information
            break;

        case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle newly created processes (main thread)
            // Process debugEvent.u.CreateProcessInfo for detailed information
            break;

        case EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle thread exit
            // Process debugEvent.u.ExitThread for detailed information
            break;

        case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle process exit
            // Process debugEvent.u.ExitProcess for detailed information
            DebugActiveProcessStop(PEInformation.processInfo.dwProcessId);
            return TRUE;

        case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle DLL loading
            // Process debugEvent.u.LoadDll for detailed information
            break;

        case UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle DLL unloading
            // Process debugEvent.u.UnloadDll for detailed information
            break;

        case OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT:
            // Handle output of debug strings
            // Process debugEvent.u.DebugString for detailed information
            break;
            // Handle other debug events as needed

        }

        // Continue execution of the traced process
        ContinueDebugEvent(debugEvent.dwProcessId, debugEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP` was in 2 case: 1.) you set TF if EFlags (0x100) 2.) you ser DRx bp

Comment: On x86, when the program generates an INT 3, you get EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT in the debugger. When the program generates an INT 1, you get EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP in the debugger. INT 1 is generated by setting the Trap Flag on the processor, which executes the INT 1 after every single instruction, permitting the debugger to snoop around and possibly resume execution until it reaches a point that matches a high-level statement in the source language for a step in or step over behaviour as reckoned by the debug symbols generated by the compiler and the loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys in the comments are great guys) Thanks @Wyck and @RbMm

### SOLUTION

```
BOOL TraceProcess()
{
    DEBUG_EVENT debugEvent;

    bool IsRunning = true;     
    CONTEXT Context{}; Context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    while (IsRunning)
    {
        if (!WaitForDebugEvent(&debugEvent, INFINITE))
        {
            // Error handling
            DebugActiveProcessStop(debugEvent.dwProcessId);
            return FALSE;
        } 

        HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, debugEvent.dwThreadId);
        if (!hThread) { std::cerr << "hThread is NULL" << std::endl; return false; }

        // Process the debug event based on its type
        switch (debugEvent.dwDebugEventCode)
        {
        case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
            switch (debugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
            {
            case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
                if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, &Context))
                {
                    std::cerr << "GetThreadContext failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                    break;
                }

                Context.EFlags |= 0x100;

                if (!SetThreadContext(hThread, &Context))
                {
                    std::cerr << "SetThreadContext failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                    break;
                }

                std::cout << "rip: " << std::hex << Context.Rip << std::endl;
                CloseHandle(hThread);
                break;
            case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP:
                if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, &Context))
                {
                    std::cerr << "GetThreadContext failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                std::bitset<32> flags(Context.EFlags);

                if (!flags[8])
                {
                    Context.EFlags |= 0x100;
                    if (!SetThreadContext(hThread, &Context))
                    {
                        std::cerr << "SetThreadContext failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                CloseHandle(hThread);
                break;
            }
            break;

        case CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle newly created threads
            // Process debugEvent.u.CreateThread for detailed information
            break;

        case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle newly created processes (main thread)
            // Process debugEvent.u.CreateProcessInfo for detailed information
            break;

        case EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle thread exit
            // Process debugEvent.u.ExitThread for detailed information
            break;

        case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle process exit
            // Process debugEvent.u.ExitProcess for detailed information
            DebugActiveProcessStop(debugEvent.dwProcessId);
            return TRUE;

        case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle DLL loading
            // Process debugEvent.u.LoadDll for detailed information
            break;

        case UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Handle DLL unloading
            // Process debugEvent.u.UnloadDll for detailed information
            break;

        case OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT:
            // Handle output of debug strings
            // Process debugEvent.u.DebugString for detailed information
            break;
            // Handle other debug events as needed

        }

        // Continue execution of the traced process
        ContinueDebugEvent(debugEvent.dwProcessId, debugEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `+` for bit manipulation, you don't want carries.  Use bitwise-OR (`|` and compound assignment version `|=`)

Comment: Also you are leaking thread handles all over the place.  Open the thread once, use the handle as many times as necessary, then call `CloseHandle`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks! As I understand it, debugEvent.dwThreadId has the id where some event happened, and because of this, it cannot be obtained just once, since during the operation of the application, its "working" threads may change in the case of multithreaded applications

Comment: Leo, are you replying to a since deleted comment by @BenVoigt? Because he's right that you need to close those thread handles that you open or you'll soon run out. --- The good news is that you don't need to open those handles in the first place: The Thread Create event gives you a handle to the thread. You just need to store that in some look-up structure so that you can find it from the thread id you are given in the other debug events.